# Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1433

Tags: mysql, node.js, macos

I'm trying to connect to my local MySql server from node.js/express application using `mssql` with following config:

```
// Database connection
var sql = require('mssql');
var config = {
    user: 'db_user',
    password: 'db_pass',
    server: 'localhost',
    database: 'project_db'
};
sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

I get this error:

```
{ [ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1433]
  name: 'ConnectionError',
  message: 'Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1433',
  code: 'ESOCKET' }
```

I know I have to enable TCP/IP connections for my local MySql server, but I can not find how to do it on OSX El Capitan. There is nothing like control panel with settings. That's all available at System Preferences > MySql:
[image]
Any ideas how to fix this, guys? Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Use port 3306? Thats what MySQL normally listens on, not 1433

Comment: Can you give a tip how to change it?

Comment: Also please post the code where you actually open the MySQL connection

Comment: Updated the database connection code, but it's nothing special there

Comment: It's always good to post a least a _minimal_ version of the exact code that generates an error, no matter how simple it seems. In this case, what you updated your post with was exactly what I needed to confirm the issue with confidence ;) happy coding!

Comment: Oh, great) I am new to this, and got one tutorial where it was done via `mssql`, so I was wondering why it's going an error in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mssql and mysql are two very different things... You should use the node-mysql or some other mysql client library if you are going to be running mysql on your dev machine

https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
  database : 'my_db'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```